# Picard number and torsion of Neron-Severi group of abelian varieties over a number field

Tags: arithmetic-geometry

Let $A$ be an abelian variety over a number field $k$ and let $NS_A$ denote its Neron-Severi scheme. Then the group of $k$-rational points of $NS_A$ is a finitely generated abelian group, i.e. $NS_A(k)=H^0(G_k,NS_A(\bar k)) = \mathbb{Z}^\rho \oplus Torsion$. I'd like to know:

What does a torsion element look like? Can it be ample? Is there an easy example, maybe of an elliptic curve, where the torsion of $NS_A(k)$ is non-trivial?

Is the rank $\rho$ of $NS_A(k)$, i.e. the Picard number, bounded by 1 and the square of the dimension of $A$?

Is the group of $\bar k$-rational points of $NS_A$ also a finitely generated abelian group?

Comment: For an abelian variety A, the Neron-Severi group is torsion-free and (when tensored with Q) is isomorphic to the set of symmetric elements in the endomorphism algebra. The endomorphism algebras of abelian varieties (as algebras with involution) are well understood (see, for example, Mumford, Abelian Varieties). 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There were quite a few different questions, so forgive me if my answer is somewhat fragmented.

The Néron-Severi group $NS(X)$ (divisors modulo algebraic equivalence) is finitely generated over any field for any non-singular projective variety $X$, this is Severi's theorem of the base (at least for the case of characteristic zero). In what follows however I am assume that the variety is defined over $\mathbb{C}$ for simplicity. Some answers to your other questions:

- In the case of curves, $NS(X)\cong\mathbb{Z}$, with the isomorphism given by the degree map.
- More generally, there is a natural injective morphism $NS(X) \to H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$. This can then be used to get an upper bound for the Picard number.
- Torsion in $NS(X)$ also naturally lives inside $H_1(X,\mathbb{Z})$, so if this is torsion free then so is $NS(X)$. This is the case free for abelian varieties (over $\mathbb{C}$ say), since $H_1(X,\mathbb{Z})$ can identified with a lattice $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{C}^g$ such that $X\cong\mathbb{C}^g/\Lambda$.
- Finally, torsion divisors can never be ample because they are numerically trivial, and ampleness is preserved under numerical equivalence.

Comment: $H^1(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is always torsion free. In fact, $NS(X)$ injects into $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ via the exponential sequence.

Comment: Yes I think I need $H_1(X,\mathbb{Z})$ instead, I shall edit my answer accordingly. Although should not numerically trivial divisors also be homologically trivial, so sent to zero in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: @Ulrich. Actually I see now why $NS(X)\to H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is in fact injective. Thanks!

Comment: How about the torsion-freeness of $H_1(X,\mathbb{Z})$ for abelian varieties over number fields?

Comment: @stefan: I was trying to be careful since if you want to do cohomology and stuff for varieties over arbitrary fields you should probably use something like étale cohomology instead. However, I guess that didnt make clear that almost any functor you care about in algebraic geometry behaves nicely with respect to base change. 

Comment: This means that there are injections $F(X) \to F(\overline{X})$, where $\overline{X}$ is the base change of $X$ to $\mathbb{C}$, and $F$ can be the Picard group, Néron-severi group or your favourite cohomology theory. So if there is no torsion in the Néron-severi group over $\mathbb{C}$ then there is certainly none over the ground field.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks for the answer. How about the boundedness of the rank? And since $NS(\bar A)$ is a fin. gen. torsion-free ab. gr., for $\bar A=A/k \times_k \mathbb{C}$, I can conclude that $NS_A(k)$ and $NS_A(\bar k)$ (with notation from my question) are also fin. gen. torsion-free ab. gr., because they are subgroups?


Answer (score 7):

Regarding the bounds for the Picard number $\rho$, the lower bound $\rho \geq 1$ comes from the fact that there exist divisors which are not algebraically equivalent to 0 (alternatively, one can argue that $\operatorname{id}_A$ is a symmetric endomorphism of $A$). The upper bound $\rho \leq (\dim A)^2$ (which holds only in characteristic 0) is Exercise 2.6(5) in Birkenhake-Lange's book *Complex abelian varieties*.

It is possible to show further that if $A$ is an abelian variety over $\mathbf{C}$ of dimension $\geq 2$, then $\rho = (\dim A)^2$ if and only if $A$ is isogenous to a power of some CM elliptic curve (see Exercise 5.6(10) in the same book).